# Salesforce DX: How to track custom objects' changes in custom profiles?

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx, custom-profile, scratch-org, sourcecontrol

Salesforce DX does not track some of the changes I make on my scratch org.

How to reproduce a problem:

1. Create a custom profile -> `sfdx force:source:pull`
2. Create a custom object -> `sfdx force:source:pull`
3. Delete a custom object -> `sfdx force:source:pull`
4. `sfdx force:source:status` shows no problems

Then an interesting thing might be observed - opening a new scratch org and pushing a source there causes the following error:

```
PROJECT PATH                            ERROR
─────────────────────────────────────── ────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\profiles\My Custom Profile.profile-meta.xml  In field: field - no CustomObject named Custom_Object__c found

The problem is that in the "My Custom Profile.profile-meta.xml" file there's still a <layoutAssignments>` section which I have to delete manually:

    <layoutAssignments>
      <layout>Custom_Object__c-Custom Object Layout</layout>
    </layoutAssignments>
```

My question is: Can I make SFDX to track these changes somehow?

PS Another thing is that it looks like a bug a bit but I'm just not sure.

**Update 11/04/20:**

The bug has been fixed on the [Winter '20 Patch 7.0](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=222007000)

Older Update:
I've reported this case and Salesforce Support identified it as a bug:

```
[Deleting a custom field/object should remove references with force:source:pull][2]
Help to resolve this problem by clicking "This Issue Affects Me".
```

Comment: This isnt really an answer so I will comment but I run into this issue a lot when working with sfdx. It happens whenever I delete a custom field. I have to go through the xml files manually and remove the references and then it seems to work. It only seems to happen to me on delete though. I figure it is a bug. Maybe we should open an issue since it seems to be something that is happening to multiple people.

Comment: Question: when you say "opening a new scratch org and pulling a source there" do you mean pushing source? Not sure what you'd pull from a newly created scratch org.

Comment: @ZackWalton As I said - I wasn't sure about that but since I know it affects more people I've decided to report a bug.

Comment: @WadeWegner Yup, youre right :)

Comment: I've updated status of the case

Comment: @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń, I suggest you post your Update as an answer that solves the problem. Because your question still comes up when filtering for unanswered questions (with a very high score).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Salesforce this bug was fixed in the [Winter '20 Patch 7.0](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=222007000).

I can confirm it, as it was gone in my Developer Edition Org.