# Deletion of custom field on standard object not detected by force:source:pull

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I did the following:

1. In my scratch org I created a custom field (on a Standard Object).
2. Then I executed force:source:pull so I had that custom field in my project folder.
3. I created a new scratch org and pushed the sources into that scratch org.
4. I deleted in that scratch org the custom field.
5. I executed force:source:pull but it says "No results found", same with force:source:status

Interestingly a deleted field on a custom object does get pulled, but not a custom field on a standard object (at least that's what it looks like according to my tests).

Is that behaviour intended, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

The problem is, that I cannot simply delete the field in my project-folder, because then I have to manually edit all the profiles and layouts and delete the field-reference there as well, because otherwise there are errors when trying to push the sources into a new scratch org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check below link of @notmyf4ulty .. She already raised the ticket to salesforce ...
[Salesforce DX: How to track custom objects' changes in custom profiles?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205717/salesforce-dx-how-to-track-custom-objects-changes-in-custom-profiles)

Comment: Hope this helped you..if yes please vote

Comment: Yes. Not the exact same problem, but basically it seems to be the same issue... thank you!